# Weighted Overlay Decimal Values for Evaluation Scale

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, overlay

I would like to do a weighted overlay of different raster datasets. I would like my evaluation scale to be from 1 to 10 with 0.1 as the incremental value. This way for example a criteria could have the value 1.2. So far ArcGIS does not let me enter decimal points. Any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: Pretty sure the tool outputs an integer raster (it requires them as inputs aka criteria), so you can't have decimal values as results. You'll also notice your weights have to total 100%, and that the [help file](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/How_Weighted_Overlay_works/009z000000s1000000/) indicates that your evaluation scale should match the classification of your inputs (including increments, which since the inputs have to be ints means no decimal).

Answer (score 1):

Do a weighted overlay with scale from 1 - 100 and then rescale with raster calculator?
if the scale is 1 - 100 then you rescale something like [(grid - min value from grid) * (max scale value - min scale value) / (max value from grid - min value from grid)] + min scale value to 1 - 10 but somewhere in there you will need to specify decimals, maybe a weighted sum would be better

Comment: What you wrote in your comment would probably suffice as a minimum length answer - there is an **edit** button beneath your answer that you can use to copy/paste that into it.